# Run-time error '424' Object Required : Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to coding and I am trying to copy data's from one worksheet to another worksheet on a particular rows.

```
Sub copycolumns()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '*/error shows here/*
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
        erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

What I am missing in here?

Comment: I would guess Rows is not an object.

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have a sheet with a codename of `Sheet1`?

Comment: @Comintern  Yes, I have. And it does not work for me.

Comment: I am trying to Copy particular rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Sheet1 is were the data lies and Sheet2 is were I want the data to be copied.

Comment: The sheet name is not the same as the code name. Does it show up as `Sheet1 (Sheet1)` in the project explorer?

Comment: Works fine for me too. If you paste it into a new workbook with 2 sheets, I bet it will also work fine.  You could try referring to the worksheets by name instead of by codename.  (Use `Range("Sheet1").` instead of `Sheet1.`, assuming that is the name showing on the tab at the bottom of the worksheet.  It's odd that you're back and forth between both methods.

Comment: @KenWhite assuming `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").CodeName` is `"Sheet1"`, then `Sheet1` is a global/project-scope identifier automagically declared by VBA, yes. And using code-name identifiers like this is absolutely the single most robust way of accessing a worksheet that exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Except, given the error number, I very much suspect that OP doesn't know that, and `Option Explicit` isn't specified, and `Sheet1` was deleted and another sheet was added and its `Name` was set to `"Sheet1"`, yet the worksheet object probably has a code-name like `Sheet4` or something.

Comment: The only other scenario I can think of is that there is an actual global variable declared somewhere else named `Sheet1`, but I'm going with @MathieuGuindon's suspicion on this one.

Comment: @Vijay - Let's determine for sure what your worksheets are called.  Run this sub:  `Sub listShts(): Dim s: For Each s In Sheets: Debug.Print "Name=" & s.Name, "CodeName=" & s.CodeName: Next s: End Sub` (all on one line like that is fine) and check the results in the immediate pane (Ctrl+G)

Comment: ...Or, there are multiple workbooks open and the intended one is not the active one.  . . . no point in speculating though.

Comment: @ashleedawg The active workbook should be irrelevant - using the code name of the sheet is scoped to the project and doesn't refer implicitly to the active workbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error 424 "object required" has only one reason to pop up on that line of code.

`Option Explicit` isn't specified, and `Sheet1` isn't declared anywhere.

Look at the properties of your "Sheet1" module (F4), then note the value of the `(Name)` property:

[image: Properties of module 'Sheet1']

The `Name` property is what you're seeing in Excel. The `(Name)` property isn't visible anywhere in Excel, and that value determines the name of a global-scope identifier that VBA declares automagically for you.

You can't do `Sheet1.Cells(...)` if no worksheet has a `(Name)` property value of `Sheet1`.

But specify `Option Explicit` anyway. The reason for error 424 is that `Sheet1` being undeclared, at run-time it's an implicit `Variant` with the default value of `Empty`, which isn't an object, thus against which a member call is illegal - only an object could ever possibly have a `Cells` member.

Protip: give the `(Name)` property a meaningful name, e.g. `SummarySheet`. Then you can do `SummarySheet.Cells(...)`.

Comment: ++ nicely explained :)